# How to combine .frm and .ibd file in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a problem with my MySQL Database.
I reinstalled my Operating System, of course, I backed up my .frm and ibdata
But, when i tried to open the database, MySQL won't read any of the data in there,
the files aren't corrupt because I can open them with other programs. 
Can someone tell me how could I repair this, because I tried with several commands, some told me to modify the my.ini, some told me to try with third party programs, but none of them didn't work.

I would really appreciate someone trying to help me

EDIT: Links to my.cnf and error:

pastebin.com/smQz4Pj1 -My.cfg 
 pastebin.com/BQky47dA -Error

Comment: Show us `my.cnf` configuration file and `mysql.log` file.

Comment: *"the files aren't corrupt because I can open them with other programs."*  That's a non sequitur.  A file can easily be "Corrupt" without also being "unreadable."  Unreadability is on a small subset of corruption.  Your question needs to be *much* more specific -- entries from the error log, for a start.

Comment: The reasons should be shown in the mysql error log. Post that. It could be numerous causes.

Comment: Sure, here you go:  https://pastebin.com/smQz4Pj1 -My.cfg and https://pastebin.com/BQky47dA -Error

Comment: Does the MySQL user (whom ever that is) have permissions to the directory and files?

Comment: Were any tables using .ibd files?  If so, then these would need to be restored as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you see `mysqld: ready for connections` this means that MySQL server was started well. In your logs:

```
2017-03-31T22:45:44.415143Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

Also you can see there:

```
2017-03-31T22:46:14.125231Z 13 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

It means that you need to change root password. I think you never assign password for `root` database user after MySQL server was installed. You can do it by command:

```
mysql_secure_installation
```